# Is Plancherel's theorem true for tempered distribution?

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f, g\in L^{2},$ by Plancherel's theorem, we have

$$\langle f, g \rangle= \langle \hat{f}, \hat{g} \rangle.$$

> My Question is:
>   Is it true that:
>   $$\langle f, g \rangle= \langle \hat{f}, \hat{g} \rangle$$

for  $f\in \mathcal{S'}(\mathbb R^d)$ (tempered distribution) and $g\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^d)$(Schwartz space)? If yes, how to justify.

Comment: Yes, because $\hat f$ is _defined_ by passing the hat to the test function. There are some complex conjugates to sort out in the scalar product, that's all.

Comment: Thanks a lot; would you please explain bit more?

Comment: Plancherel's theorem in $L^2$ involves inner products, whereas the distributional pairing does not. You have to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

One has to be careful with complex conjugation here. The claimed identity is 
$$
\int f \bar g = \int \hat f \bar {\hat g} 
 \tag1$$
Conjugating the (unitary) Fourier transform gives the inverse Fourier transform of conjugation. So,
$$
\int \hat f\bar {\hat g}  = \int \hat f \check {\bar g} 
\tag2$$
The right hand side is the value of distribution $\hat f$ on test function $\check {\bar g} $. By the definition of $\hat f$, this is computed by passing the hat to the test function, which cancels out the inverse hat:
$$
\int \hat f \check {\bar g}  = \int   f \bar g
\tag3$$

Comment: but you should not enter the space $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n) \subset \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and its dual?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer lies in this characterization:

[Explicit characterization of dual of $H^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1694713/explicit-characterization-of-dual-of-h1)

knowing, in particular, that $\mathcal{F} : \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n) \longrightarrow \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is an isomorphism, extension of $\mathcal{F}:L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) \longrightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

TrialAndError did you notice that there is no scalar product in the space of tempered distributions. But you can understand this, in the sense of the characterization of dual space $H^s({\mathbb{R}^n})^*$, or simply of $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
For any $f\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, there exists a sequence $f_{n}\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $f_{n}\to f$ under the topology of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. According to Plancherel's theorem, we have $\langle f_{n},g\rangle=\langle\hat{{f}_{n}},\hat{g}\rangle$. Then by tending $n$ to $\infty$ we have $\langle f,g\rangle=\langle\hat{f},\hat{g}\rangle$.

Notation: if $f_{n}\to f$ under the topology of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, we have $\hat{f_{n}}\to\hat{f}$ under the topology of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.