# Is there a Plancherel-type identity for generalized Fourier Transforms?

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $S$ be in $\mathcal{T}$, the set of tempered distributions, and $\mathcal{F}S$ be its Fourier Transform. **Is there some relationship for such distributions, analogous to the Plancherel Theorem for $f \in L^2$?**

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lvert f(x) \rvert^2 \ dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lvert \mathcal{F}f(k) \rvert^2 dk $$

I suspect that perhaps this is not possible to define in general due to the difficulties in defining the convolution of two distributions with non-compact support and/or associative multiplication with distributions. **However, are there some important restricted cases in which it works out?**

What follows is not at all rigorous, but just a kind of attempt at exploring how one would compute such things. I have noticed some coincidences, for instance that if we let (using the appropriate convention such that the Plancherel theorem works out as above)
$$ S = P.V. \frac{\cos{x}}{x}, \mathcal{F}S = \frac{i}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} \Big(\text{Sign}(k+1) \ + \text{Sign}(k-1) \Big)   $$
forging ahead foolishly and treating these as functions with point-wise multiplication then we have to evaluate 
$$ \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos^2{x}}{x^2} dx$$ and $$\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg( \int_{-\infty}^{-1} 1 \ dk + \int_{1}^{\infty} 1 \ dk\bigg)$$

The most 'natural' thing I could think to do is take the product of two principal-value distributions to lead to the Hadamard regularization $$\mathcal{H} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos^2{x}}{x^2} = -\pi $$ and cut off the second integral by hand $$\lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{\pi}{2}\bigg( \int_{-a}^{-1} 1 \ dk + \int_{1}^{a} 1 \ dk\bigg) \sim \pi \ a - \pi $$ and somehow the finite parts of both 'expressions' (what you get when you just throw away the divergent parts) are the same. **Is there some good reason that these finite parts should be the same, or is it merely coincidental?**

Comment: if $S$ is a distribution and $T_x$ the shift operator, then for any two test-functions : $\phi(x) \langle S, T_x \varphi  \rangle = \phi (S \ast \varphi) \in L^2$ (can you prove is even a test function ?). if $S$ is indeed a function of $L^2$, the usual Plancherel theorem is obtained with $\varphi \to \delta, \phi \to 1$

Comment: for example, can you prove using the Plancherel theorem for the Fourier transform on $L^2$ and what I wrote the Plancherel theorem for the Fourier series ?

Comment: @user1952009 What you have called $S$ and what I have called $S$ don't seem to be the same thing. What you have written would give something like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S(y) \varphi(x-y) dy dx$. But, by an analogue for the Plancherel theorem, I mean something that gives meaning to $ \langle S, S \rangle$ (or $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} S(x) S(x) dx $ to be less precise)

Comment: what ? $S_{regularized}(x) = \phi(x) \int_{-\infty}^\infty S(y) \varphi(y-x) dy$. and for relating the principal value of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(x)^2}{x^2}dx$ to the FT and the Plancherel theorem, you'll need such regularization. and of course $\langle S, S \rangle$ is undefined, but $\langle S_{regularized},S_{regularized} \rangle$ is..

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood. By,$ \phi (S \ast \varphi)$ you did mean multiplication and not what I wrote. Yes, this is headed in the direction that I thought it should be, let me think about what you wrote.

Comment: and if $S$ is a tempered distribution, you can replace "test function" with "Schwartz function", for example $\phi(x) = e^{-x^2 \epsilon^2}$, $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{\epsilon \sqrt{\pi}} e^{-x^2/\epsilon^2}$

Comment: A similar question was asked here:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705527/is-plancherels-theorem-true-for-tempered-distribution/1709371#1709371