# Proof of proposition2.4.7 in Classical Fourier Analysis: A detail about $\langle u,\Psi\rangle=\langle\hat{u},\hat{\Psi}\rangle$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

I want to ask a detail in the book "Classical Fourier Analysis" by Loukas Grafakos

Proof of proposition2.4.7 in page 141 in Classical Fourier Analysis,3rd: A detail about $\langle u,\Psi\rangle=\langle\hat{u},\hat{\Psi}\rangle$. In the proof, why does the author use $\langle u,\Psi\rangle=\langle\hat{u},\hat{\Psi}\rangle$? **Does it right?**
Why not $\langle u,\Psi\rangle=\langle\hat{u},\check{\Psi}\rangle$?

Notation:$u$ represents a tempered distribution and in $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus\lbrace0\rbrace)$,$\Psi$ is a nonnegtive, radial, smooth, and nonzero function on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ support in the annulus $1<|x|<2$.

[image][image][image]

Comment: What exactly is $\check \Psi$ as opposed to $\hat \Psi$? Presumably, $\hat u$ denotes the Fourier transform of $u$, what's $\check \Psi$ then?

Comment: $\check{\Psi}$ is the inverse fourier transform of $\Psi$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Yes, the author is correct. The statement follows as a consequence of [Plancherel’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem)

Comment: Thank you for your help, in addition, is Plancherel's Theorem valid in distribution theory? In other words, does Plancherel's theorem can be used for tempered distribution $u$ in the above question?

Comment: It would be nice if you gave the text, a snapshot from the book would do, instead of just the reference.

Comment: @AD - Stop Putin  Thank you for your advice, and now I add three pictures.

Comment: @monotoneoperator That's a good point. I assumed so, but perhaps not... [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1705527/81360) seems to indicate that you might have the right idea

Comment: @Ben Grossmann
 Thank you very much, I benefit a lot from the link you post!!!Best wishes!!

Comment: @monotoneoperator I’m glad to hear it, you’re welcome!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705527/is-plancherels-theorem-true-for-tempered-distribution I answer the question under this post by myself.

Answer (score 1):

[Is Plancherel's theorem true for tempered distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705527/is-plancherels-theorem-true-for-tempered-distribution)
I have answered this question under the above post and now for readers' convenience, I copy the answer here:

Yes.
For any $f\in\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, there exists a sequence $f_{n}\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that $f_{n}\to f$ under the topology of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. According to Plancherel's theorem, we have $\langle f_{n},g\rangle=\langle\hat{{f}_{n}},\hat{g}\rangle$. Then by tending $n$ to $\infty$ we have $\langle f,g\rangle=\langle\hat{f},\hat{g}\rangle$.

Notation: if $f_{n}\to f$ under the topology of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, we have $\hat{f_{n}}\to\hat{f}$ under the topology of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^{n})$.